# AndroidX test dialog

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, androidx, androidx-test

Since AndroidX release we are using Robolectric with Espresso in our unit tests. But we are unable to find a way to test dialogs.
Espresso community suggests we do:

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.button1))
                .inRoot(isDialog())
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
                .perform(click())
```

But the test here fails with exception

```
Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not request layout for 10 seconds.
```

When debugging the code, we found that dialog is found, but somehow `decorView.hasWindowFocus()` returns false.

Is it because of some bug in Robolectric that view cannot get window focus? Is there a way to resolve it? At the moment we are resorting back to Robolectric shadows.

We are using `Robolectric 4.2` and `AndroidX test 1.1.0` versions

**Update:**
Apparently after showing dialog, activity keeps Window focus, so it is most probably Robolectric bug (or my misunderstanding).

Answer (score 1):

Robolectric has a method for that, it's

```java
ShadowAlertDialog.getLatestDialog()
```

To perform a click action on the OK button you can use it like this:

```java
((AlertDialog) ShadowAlertDialog.getLatestDialog())
        .getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
```